# Simple javascript code for a button doesn't work in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to make a little script for a button on my website, but it doesn't work in any browser.

I don't see why it doesn't work. Can you guys take a look at it please to see what's wrong.

This is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Magic</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
    div {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('div').mouseenter(function() {
        $('div').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });

    $('div').mouseleave(function() {
        $('div').fadeTo('slow', 0.25);
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `jquery.js` to your page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Magic</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Note, that above example is using a copy of jQuery 1.10.2 from Google's CDN. You can amend this to a different version if required.

Comment: How do I know which version I have to use?

Comment: You should always use the latest one, unless you have some specific functionality you need to support.